# Extended timestamp as default in minicom

Tags: serial-port

I recently started using `minicom` and I always need to do

- Ctrl+A+n (x2): Timestamp every line (extended)

I didn't found anything neither in the `man` (except for)

`N    Toggle between three states, whether each line is prefixed with current date and time, a timestamp is added every second, or no timestamps.`

nor in the minicom setup (`minicom -s`).

Is there a way to make this the default behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use -O timestamp=extended, so type in terminal for example:

```
minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0 -O timestamp=extended
```

This has been updated with minicom 2.8

Answer (score 3):

Apparently [there is no such option](https://alioth-lists.debian.net/pipermail/minicom-devel/2017/001357.html) as of writing, so I created [a patch](https://salsa.debian.org/minicom-team/minicom/-/merge_requests/10) for that. With that patch, appending `line_timestamp extended` to `~/.minirc.dfl` enables extended timestamp by default.

Update 2021/01/21: use strings literals (extended) instead of numeric constants (2) following the latest version of my patch.